# Ambiguous reference of '\n' in lexer and parser rules in ANTLR 4

Tags: c#, parsing, c#-4.0, antlr, antlr4

**First: This is not a syntactic error! My grammar file does not contain any error!**
I want to write a C# grammar for my program. I have downloaded this grammar from CodePlex:
[ANTLR C# 4.0 Grammar](http://antlrcsharp.codeplex.com/)
I have not found better C# grammar for ANTLR 4. This grammar does not support documentation comments which are very important for my program. This grammar skips all the comments, so I have deleted the skiping of documentation comments and written my code for documentation comments, but **I don't know how to say, that after "\n" has to be "///". I am afraid, that the lexer, when he recognizes "\n", skips the lexical symbol automatically and never match this: ('\n' '///')? in my parser rule**. Does anyone know, how to solve this problem? Or Could anyone explain to me, that my code is right, if it is?

Here is my parser rules for documentation comments:

```
//documentation comments
doc_comment :
'///' (  summary remarks?
        |remarks
        );
summary :
    '<summary' cref? '>' (('\n' '///')* comment_text ('\n' '///')*)* tag_body+ (('\n' '///')* comment_text ('\n' '///')*)* '</summary>';
remarks :
    '<remarks' cref? '>' (('\n' '///')* comment_text ('\n' '///')*)* '</remarks>';
tag_body :   '<c' cref? '>' (('\n' '///')* comment_text ('\n' '///')*)* '</c>'
            |'<code' cref? '>' (('\n' '///')* comment_text ('\n' '///')*)* '</code>'
            |'<example' cref? '>' (('\n' '///')* comment_text ('\n' '///')*)* '</example>'
            |'<exception' cref? '>' (('\n' '///')* comment_text ('\n' '///')*)* '</exception>'
            |'<include' 'file' '=' '\'' comment_text '\'' 'path' '=' '\'' comment_text ('[' '@name' '=' '"'identifier '"' ']')? '\'' '/' '>'
            |'<list' 'type' '=' ('"bullet"' | '"number"' | '"table"') '>' ('\n' '///')* listheader? listitem? '</list>' 
            |'<para' cref? '>' (('\n' '///')* comment_text ('\n' '///')*)* '</para>' 
            |'<param' 'name' '=' '"' identifier '"' '>' (('\n' '///')* comment_text ('\n' '///')*)* '</param>'
            |'<paramref' 'name' '=' '"' comment_text '"' '/' '>'
            |'<permission' cref? '>' (('\n' '///')* comment_text ('\n' '///')*)* '</permission>'
            |'<returns' cref? '>' (('\n' '///')* comment_text ('\n' '///')*)* '</returns>'
            |'<see' cref '/' '>'
            |'<seealso' cref '/' '>'
            |'<typeparam' 'name' '=' '"' comment_text '"' '>' (('\n' '///')* comment_text ('\n' '///')*)* '</typeparam>'
            |'<typeparamref' 'name' '=' '"' comment_text '"' '/' '>'
            |'<value' cref? '>' (('\n' '///')* comment_text ('\n' '///')*)* '</value>';
cref : 'cref' '=' '"' comment_text '"' ;
listheader : '<listheader>' ('<term>' (('\n' '///')* comment_text ('\n' '///')*)* '</term>')? ('<description>' (('\n' '///')* comment_text ('\n' '///')*)* '</description>')? '</listheader>';
listitem : '<listitem>' ('<term>' (('\n' '///')* comment_text ('\n' '///')*)* '</term>')? ('<description>' (('\n' '///')* comment_text ('\n' '///')*)* '</description>')? '</listitem>';
```

And here is a lexer rules for white spaces (WS), a parser rule for comment_text and a lexer rule for comment chars (ANY_CHARS):

```
WS:
    (' '  |  '\r'  |  '\t'  |  '\n'  ) -> skip;
comment_text : ANY_CHARS;
fragment ANY_CHARS: (.)*;
```

Thanks for replies!

Pete

Comment: I do not use ANTLR, so this is just my opinion: I think you are much better off keeping the original parser that ignores comments, using that to identify all method declarations or other identifiers that you might be interested in, then with that information in hand, re-scan the lines of source files leading up to an identifier for any documentation comments. The comments syntax is somewhat orthogonal to the regular context free C# syntax, which would make it difficult, I think, to write a uniform grammar that could handle both without becoming quite messy.

Comment: You seem certain that your grammar does not contain syntax errors, but C# documentation comments are not limited to the items you described above. Some others that are *actually used* in my code include `<strong`, `<em`, `<threadsafety`, `<preliminary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure it's theoretically possible to parse the XML documentation comments at the same time as the rest of your file, but it's a maintenance nightmare, especially for the lexer rules. For example, how would you handle the following?

```
/// <see
///      cref="Something"
/// />
```

Instead of taking this approach, you should do the following.

1. Move all documentation comment tokens to their own channel.

   ```
   @members {
       public const int DocCommentsChannel = 2;
   }

   DOC_COMMENT : '///' ~[\r\n]* -> channel(DocCommentsChannel);
   LINE_COMMENT : '//' ~[\r\n]* -> channel(HIDDEN);
   ```
2. After parsing, write code to examine the `ITokenStream` for all instances of tokens on the `DocCommentsChannel` channel leading up to the declaration of some item, and process them as a group. Using a separate parser. This would be most easily performed by creating an in-memory XML representation of the comment by removing the leading `///` characters from each line and placing the resulting block of text as the body of a root element like `<Comment>{Your comment text here}</Comment>`. You could then call [`XDocument.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb551294.aspx) to load the comment and process it from there as you see fit.

Comment: It is not exactly what I wanted, but it is possible to do it this way and I thank you. I need rules in documentation comments, because it has some rules in C#. There are tags with different meaning, that I have to parse to general XML. I will work with the documentaion in general XML by the same method for all other languages, for example Java. Java have different comments, that is why I have to transfer it.

Comment: @user3245590 If you add rules for documentation comments to your C# parser, then errors in the comments could prevent the parser from continuing to parse your C# code and output error messages which are difficult for most people to understand. By analyzing your comments separately from other code, you can produce much better error messages and ensure that only parse errors in the actual code impact the parser's ability to produce a parse tree.